# Login required error in Canvas lms for an LTI 1.3 Tool launch

Tags: lti, canvas-lms

I'm trying to launch an LTI 1.3 tool from canvas lms. I'm getting the error `login_required` with the error description `Must have an active user session` after sending the parameters as specified in step 2(authentication request) as per the [official documentation](https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/file.lti_dev_key_config.html).  This is not happening while I try from a public course. I went through the source code and found that the error is occurring around [here](https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/blob/master/app/controllers/lti/ims/authentication_controller.rb#L102).

This is due to a missing user session. For some reason, `@current_user` is empty for me. However, I am logged in and am trying to access the tool. I don't know why this error is happening. I have been at this for a week. It would be nice if anyone could throw some light on this.

I found a similar [query](https://community.canvaslms.com/t5/Canvas-Developers-Group/login-required-error-when-course-is-not-published-and-or/m-p/531051) in the canvas developer community but it's unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many reasons why this can happen. Personally, for me, I was doing a server-to-server call instead of a simple redirect. Hence canvas couldn't validate the user session. I changed and it's working for me. I'm posting this in case anyone stumbles up on this issue. This is mentioned in the [documentation](https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/file.lti_dev_key_config.html) and I missed it earlier.